# How get new installed product attribute in magento (using helper) on category pages

Tags: magento-1.9, php, module, helper

I've installed new product attribute using my module script - `mysql4-install-1.0.0.php:`

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$setup = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup('core_setup');
$setup->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'product_display_price', array(
'group'             => 'Prices',
'label'             => 'Webdevelop Extensions - Display Price',
'type'              => 'int',
'input'             => 'select',
'backend'           => '',
'frontend'          => '',
'source'            => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
'visible'           => true,
'required'          => false,
'user_defined'      => false,
'searchable'        => false,
'filterable'        => false,
'comparable'        => false,
'visible_on_front'  => false,
'visible_in_advanced_search' => false,
'unique'            => false,
));
$installer->endSetup();
```

This attribute `('product_display_price')`

I can take on product pages, using `var_dump(getProductAttributeValueDisplayPrice())` on my rewrite block.
But when I take it on category pages I get null. the problem is that I can not catch the product on category page to read your attribute.

I use helper file `Data.php`:-

```
public function getProductAttributeValueDisplayPrice()
{
$currentProduct = Mage::registry('current_product');
if ($currentProduct) {
    $product_id = $currentProduct->getId();
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->load($product_id);
    $attribute = $product->getData('product_display_price');
    return $attribute;
}else null;
}
```

Comment: set the attribute visible on front end and use in product list to yes from Manage Attribute

Comment: This decision does not help. The problem is that I can not catch the product on category page to read your attribute.

Comment: you can not get the current product on category page  because on category page the product collection is returned. you can loop through the product collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my helper file - Data.php I added two function which set and get product

```
protected $_currentProduct = '';

public function setCurrentProduct($label)
{
    $this->_currentProduct = $label;
    return $this;
}

public function getCurrentProduct()
{
    return $this->_currentProduct;
}
```

In my block file I set product

```
$helper->setCurrentProduct($this->getProduct());
```

And I maked chenge in my helper function getProductAttributeValueDisplayPrice() - $currentProduct = $this->getCurrentProduct();

```
    public function getProductAttributeValueDisplayPrice()
{
    $currentProduct = $this->getCurrentProduct();
    if ($currentProduct) {
        $product_id = $currentProduct->getId();
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->load($product_id);
        $attribute = $product->getData('product_display_price');
        return $attribute;
    }else null;
}
```

Everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind is that you have enable the catalog_flat tables so this attribute wont load at category page bcoz it fetches data from flat tables.

**If Attribute is created then :**

To display a custom product attribute on the product list page

Go Admin -> Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes

Set "Used in Product Listing" to Yes

and for installer script

```
    <?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$setup = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup('core_setup');
$setup->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'product_display_price', array(
'group'             => 'Prices',
'label'             => 'Webdevelop Extensions - Display Price',
'type'              => 'int',
'input'             => 'select',
'backend'           => '',
'frontend'          => '',
'source'            => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
'visible'           => true,
'required'          => false,
'user_defined'      => false,
'searchable'        => false,
'filterable'        => false,
'comparable'        => false,
'visible_on_front'  => false,
'visible_in_advanced_search' => false,
'unique'            => false,
'used_in_product_listing' => '1', //list page visible 
));
$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: No. I don't want to display the value of this attribute on product list page. I want to edit my function -  getProductAttributeValueDisplayPrice() in the helper file -  Data.php. When I using  var_dump(getProductAttributeValueDisplayPrice())  on my rewrite block (in my block I rewrite functions _toHtml()) I see value of this attribute on product page. But on categories page I see null value for this product.

Comment: it will not directly display the attribute but you a use it when flat table is enable .

Comment: when you reindex then magento update the flat table data and found new attribute setting change then it will add and remove feild from flattable on this setting bases

Comment: the problem is that I can not catch the product on category page to read your attribute

Answer (score 0):

The you will either have to wrap your product model around a new instance or if you only need the one attribute then use `getAttributeRawValue()` which is less expensive
example:

```
$product->getResource()->getAttributeRawValue($product->getId(),'product_display_price',Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId());
```

Comment: This decision does not help. The problem is that I can not catch the product on category page to read your attribute.